# Column string conversion based on unique values

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy, 2d

Is there a way to replace string values in columns of a 2D array with ordered numbers in Python?

For example say you have a 2D array:

```
a = np.array([['A',0,'C'],['A',0.3,'B'],['D',1,'D']])
a
Out[57]: 
array([['A', '0', 'C'],
       ['A', '0.3', 'B'],
       ['D', '1', 'D']], dtype='<U3')
```

If I wanted to replace the string values 'A','A','D' in the first column with the numbers 0,0,1 and 'C','B','D' with 0,1,2 is there an efficient way to do so.

It may be helpful to know:

- Replacement numbers in different columns are independent of column. i.e. each column who's strings have been replaced with numbers will start with 0 and increase up to the number of unique values in that column.
- The above is a test case and the real data is a lot bigger with more columns of  strings.

Here is an example method to solve this problem I quickly came up with:

```
for  j in range(a.shape[1]):
    b = list(set(a[:,j]))
    length = len(b)
    for i in range(len(b)):
        indices = np.where(a[:,j]==b[i])[0]
        print(indices)
        a[indices,j]=i
```

However this seems like an inefficient way to achieve this and also cannot distinguish between float or string values in columns and defaults to replacing values with strings of numbers:

```
a
Out[91]: 
array([['1.0', '0.0', '2.0'],
       ['1.0', '1.0', '0.0'],
       ['0.0', '2.0', '1.0']], dtype='<U3')
```

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to do a `label encoding`.

I can think of two options: [pandas.factorize](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.factorize.html) and [sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html).

#### Using `LabelEncoder`

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

b = np.zeros_like(a, np.int) 
for column in range(a.shape[1]):
    b[:, column] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(a[:, column])
```

Then `b` will be:

```
array([[0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [1, 2, 2]])
```

If you want to be able to go back to the original values, you will need to save the encoders. You can do it this way:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

encoders = {}
b = np.zeros_like(a, np.int)
for column in range(a.shape[1]):
    encoders[column] = LabelEncoder()
    b[:, column] = encoders[column].fit_transform(a[:, column])
```

Now `encoders[0].classes_` will have:

```
array(['A', 'D'], dtype='<U3')
```

Which means that 'A' was mapped to `0` and 'D' to `1`.

Finally, if you do the encoding overriding `a` instead of using a new matrix `c`, you will obtain integers as strings (`"1"` instead of `1`), you can solve this with `astype(int`):

```
encoders = {}
for column in range(a.shape[1]):
    encoders[column] = LabelEncoder()
    a[:, column] = encoders[column].fit_transform(a[:, column])

# At this point, a will have strings instead of ints because a had type str
# array([['0', '0', '1'],
#       ['0', '1', '0'],
#       ['1', '2', '2']], dtype='<U3')

a = a.astype(int)

# Now `a` is of type int
# array([[0, 0, 1],
#        [0, 1, 0],
#        [1, 2, 2]])
```

#### Using `pd.factorize`

`factorize` returns the encoded column and the encoding mapping, so if you don't care about it you can avoid saving it:

```
for column in range(a.shape[1]):
    a[:, column], _ = pd.factorize(a[:, column]) # Drop mapping

a = a.astype(int) # same as above, it's of type str
# a is
# array([[0, 0, 1],
#        [0, 1, 0],
#        [1, 2, 2]])
```

If you want to keep the encoding mappings:

```
mappings = []
for column in range(a.shape[1]):
    a[:, column], mapping = pd.factorize(a[:, column])
    mappings.append(mapping)

a = a.astype(int)
```

Now `mappings[0]` will have the following data:

```
array(['A', 'D'], dtype=object)
```

Which has the same semantics than `encoders[0].classes_` of sklearn's LabelEncoder solution.

Comment: Many thanks! I've gone for your label encoder method in the end. Thank you for taking the time to reply

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: If I could expand on this question, is there a way to use label_encoder in conjunction with a predefined array of unique values? The reason I ask is because I would like to perform this encoding on several huge datasets which have some common string values and some uncommon and therefore the above method would give the same string a different value in different datasets whereas I need them to be encoded the same across all datasets I plan to load in.

Comment: Is it possible to have all the possible values for a column together? If it is, you can do as follows: First, fit the LabelEncoder on all the values for that column with the method `fit`: `enc = LabelEncoder(); enc.fit(all_possible_values)`. This will create the unique mapping you want in `enc`. After that, you can just transform the columns of each specific dataframe with `column = enc.transform(column)`, having the cross-dataframe consistency you want.

Comment: It's certainly possible to get all the unique values so this should work I think. Thanks again, I'll give it a try! Is there a sensible way to save an encoding once it's been fit to data for using later? Just so the process doesn't have to be done in one long script run

Comment: Just save the `encoder.classes_` with [numpy.save](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) or [pickle](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html) sklearn's encoder itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want in an efficient way with just Numpy.

Basically, you iterate over the values in each column of your input while keeping track of the observed letters in a set or dict. This is similar to what you already had, but slightly more efficient (you avoid the call to `np.where` for one thing).

Here's a function `charToIx` that will do what you want:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from string import ascii_letters

class Ix:
    def __init__(self):
        self._val = 0

    def __call__(self):
        val = self._val
        self._val += 1
        return val

def charToIx(arr, dtype=None, out=None):
    if dtype is None:
        dtype = arr.dtype

    if out is None:
        out = np.zeros(arr.shape, dtype=dtype)

    for incol,outcol in zip(arr.T, out.T):
        ix = Ix()
        cixDict = defaultdict(lambda: ix())
        for i,x in enumerate(incol):
            if x in cixDict or x in ascii_letters:
                outcol[i] = cixDict[x]
            else:
                outcol[i] = x

    return out
```

You specify the type of the output array when you call the function. So the output of:

```
a = np.array([['A',0,'C'],['A',0.3,'B'],['D',1,'D']])
print(charToIx(a, dtype=float))
```

will be a `float` array:

```
array([[0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 0.3, 1. ],
       [1. , 1. , 2. ]])
```